# How to import python-mysql package not installed in virtualenvironment?

Tags: python, mysql

I installed python-mysql using the following:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python

The issue is on install, I have only the option to pick my root python install C:\Python27 and no virtualenvironment.

When I create my virtualenv "testenv", it does not have the "python-mysql" package installed. How can I make it such that "testenv" can access the "python-mysql" installed outside of my environment using the installer from the link above?

I am running Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

If you create your virtual environment as below you will have access to the main Python packages.

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages ENV
```

It is usual to install all your packages inside the virtual environment. To do this you need to use pip or easy_install.

Comment: Issue is when i do a pip install python-mysql, it requires compilation, and oftentimes fails due to one reason or another either "missing vcvarsall.bat" or some compiler issue.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, and solved it manually moving the created files to my virtualenv. **Watch out** since it also compiles extensions. Move all the recent files/folders once you install it, to the virtualenv (i.e. If the only package/folder you installed is that, in a certain period, move all the files/folders sharing the date/time).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access module that isn't in current path, you can simply use this snippet before import:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("<path to you module>")
```